# AIOBLE on PICO W: upon disconnect I get OSError: [Errno 22] EINVAL

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

EDIT:
Thank you for engaging, Nekomatic: Suggesting the Try/Except. I'm new to programming and it's so exciting to join the community. Here is my updated code. I put the Try/Except into the peripheral task and took the remote task out of the main loop and only call it inside the Try. Extra code for the UI of the LCD screen. Please tell me if there is etiquette around posting the entire program or should I trim all the non-important stuff.

```
led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
connected = False
alive = False

"""Begin remote command sends"""
async def remote_task():
    if keyA.value() == 0:
        print('Button A pressed')
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"a")
        LCD.fill_rect(208,15,30,30,LCD.red)
    elif keyB.value() == 0:
        print('Button B pressed')
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"b")
        LCD.fill_rect(208,75,30,30,LCD.blue)  
    elif keyX.value() == 0:
        print('Button X pressed')
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"x")  
        LCD.fill_rect(208,135,30,30,LCD.green)
    elif keyY.value() == 0:
        print('Button Y pressed')
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"y")
        LCD.fill_rect(208,195,30,30,colour(255,255,0))         
    elif(up.value() == 0):
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"up")
        LCD.fill_rect(60,60,30,30,LCD.red)
        print("UP")           
    elif(dowm.value() == 0):
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"down")
        LCD.fill_rect(60,150,30,30,LCD.red)
        print("DOWM")            
    elif(left.value() == 0):
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"left")
        LCD.fill_rect(15,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        print("LEFT")       
    elif(right.value() == 0):
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"right")
        LCD.fill_rect(105,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        print("RIGHT")
    elif(ctrl.value() == 0):
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"ctrl")
        LCD.fill_rect(60,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        print("CTRL")
    else:
        LCD.fill_rect(105,105,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(105,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(60,105,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(60,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(15,105,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(15,105,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(60,150,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(60,150,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(60,60,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(60,60,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(208,195,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(208,195,30,30,colour(255,255,0))
        LCD.fill_rect(208,135,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(208,135,30,30,LCD.green)
        LCD.fill_rect(208,15,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(208,15,30,30,LCD.red)
        LCD.fill_rect(208,75,30,30,LCD.black)
        LCD.rect(208,75,30,30,LCD.blue)
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"!")       
    LCD.show()
    await asyncio.sleep_ms(10)

"""Begin Peripheral stuff"""

# Serially wait for connections. Don't advertise while a central is connected.    
async def peripheral_task():
    global connected, connection, alive
    while True:
        connected = False
        print('advertising')
        async with await aioble.advertise(
            ADV_INTERVAL_MS, 
            name="Space Cowboy Products", 
            appearance=_BLE_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_REMOTE_CONTROL, 
            services=[_REMOTE_UUID]
        ) as connection:
            print("Connection from: ", connection.device)
            connected = True
            alive = True
            print(f"connected: {connected}")
"""This is the new part"""
            while True:
                try:
                    await remote_task()
                except:
                    connection.disconnected()
                    print('disconnected')
                    alive = False
                    connected = False
                    return
                continue
        
async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(peripheral_task()),
#        asyncio.create_task(blink_task()),
#        asyncio.create_task(remote_task()),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

while True:
    asyncio.run(main())
    print('restarting')
```

With two raspberry pi pico Ws, I am able to connect, send data from one, receive on another. I want the picos to be able to handle disconnection and then try to reconnect without crashing. When I pull the power from the "Central" or robot, I get the Errno 22 on the remote.

Credit to Kevin McAleer for creating the bulk of this code and describing it on his [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0wCtKz1l78).

Here is the code

```
import sys
import aioble
import bluetooth
import machine
from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM
import uasyncio as asyncio
from micropython import const

def uid():
    """ Return the unique id of the device as a string """
    return "{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(
        *machine.unique_id())

"""Device info GATT characteristic types"""
MANUFACTURER_ID = const(0x02A29)
MODEL_NUMBER_ID = const(0x2A24)
SERIAL_NUMBER_ID = const(0x2A25)
HARDWARE_REVISION_ID = const(0x2A26)
BLE_VERSION_ID = const(0x2A28)

"""UUIDs"""
_DEVICE_INFO_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0x180A)
_GENERIC = bluetooth.UUID(0x1848)
_BUTTON_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0x2A6E)
_REMOTE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0x1800)

"""Need to figure out BLE appearances"""
_BLE_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_REMOTE_CONTROL = const(384)

"""Advertising frequency. Changing this doesn't seem to matter. Need to figure out purpose"""
ADV_INTERVAL_MS = 250_000

"""Create device_info service and characteristics"""
device_info = aioble.Service(_DEVICE_INFO_UUID)
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(MANUFACTURER_ID), read=True, initial="Kev's Robots")
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(MODEL_NUMBER_ID), read=True, initial="1.0")
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(SERIAL_NUMBER_ID), read=True, initial=uid())
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(HARDWARE_REVISION_ID), read=True, initial=sys.version)
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(BLE_VERSION_ID), read=True, initial="1.0")

"""Create remote_service service and characteristics"""
remote_service = aioble.Service(_GENERIC)
button_characteristic = aioble.Characteristic(
    remote_service, _BUTTON_UUID, read=True, notify=True)

print('registering services')
aioble.register_services(remote_service, device_info)

"""from Waveshare"""
button_a = Pin(15,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP) # Normally 1 but 0 if pressed
button_b = Pin(17,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
button_x = Pin(19,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
button_y = Pin(21,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)

up = Pin(2,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
down = Pin(18,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
left = Pin(16,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
right = Pin(20,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
ctrl = Pin(3,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)

led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
connected = False
alive = False

# Serially wait for connections. Don't advertise while a central is connected.    
async def peripheral_task():
    global connected, alive, connection
    connected = False
    while True and not alive:
        async with await aioble.advertise(
            ADV_INTERVAL_MS, 
            name="Kev's Robots", 
            appearance=_BLE_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_REMOTE_CONTROL, 
            services=[_REMOTE_UUID]
        ) as connection:
            print("Connection from: ", connection.device)
            connected = True
            alive = True
            print(f"connected: {connected}")
            await connection.disconnected(timeout_ms=None)
            alive = False
            continue

async def blink_task():
    toggle = True
    led.value(True)
    """Wait until alive to start the blink task"""
    while True and not alive:
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(250)
    print('starting blink task')
    while True and alive:
        led.value(toggle)
        toggle = not toggle
        blink = 1000
        # print(f'blink {toggle}, connected: {connected}')
        if connected:
            blink = 1000
        else:
            blink = 250
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(blink)

""" Send the event to the connected device """
async def remote_task():
    while True and not alive:
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(250)
    print('starting remote task')
    while True and alive:
        if button_a.value() == 0:
            print('Button A pressed')
#            button_characteristic.write(b"a")
            button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"a")   
        elif button_b.value() == 0:
            print('Button B pressed')
#            button_characteristic.write(b"b")
            button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"b")   
        elif button_x.value() == 0:
            print('Button X pressed')
#            button_characteristic.write(b"x")
            button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"x")   
        elif button_y.value() == 0:
            print('Button Y pressed')
#            button_characteristic.write(b"y")
            button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"y")
        else:
#            button_characteristic.write(b"!")
            button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"!")
            """keeps on crashing here on disconnect.....why?"""
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(10)
        
async def main():
    tasks = []
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(peripheral_task()),
        asyncio.create_task(blink_task()),
        asyncio.create_task(remote_task()),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

while True:
    asyncio.run(main())
    print('restarting')
```

Here is the REPL output:

```
> MPY: soft reboot
> registering services
> Connection from:  Device(ADDR_PUBLIC, 28:cd:c1:08:59:e0, CONNECTED)
> connected: True
> starting blink task
> starting remote task
> Button Y pressed
> Button Y pressed
> Button Y pressed
> Button Y pressed
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\<stdin\>", line 140, in \<module\>
> File "asyncio/core.py", line 1, in run
> File "asyncio/core.py", line 1, in run_until_complete
> File "asyncio/core.py", line 1, in run_until_complete
> File "\<stdin\>", line 137, in main
> File "asyncio/funcs.py", line 1, in gather
> File "asyncio/core.py", line 1, in run_until_complete
> File "\<stdin\>", line 126, in remote_task
> File "aioble/server.py", line 258, in notify
> OSError: \[Errno 22\] EINVAL
```

Comment: To state the obvious, it looks like something becomes invalid when the other device goes down, maybe `connection`. Is that unexpected? Can you use a `try…except` block to catch and handle the error?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I tried that and it worked. I’m brand new to programming save for a little basic 20 years ago in high school. Got a passion project cooking.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Good to know. Feel free to post your own answer showing what your solution was.